# load more items php in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i send http post requst to my api And I fill out a HTML table with the results I got
but i need to **show more results in the same html table when user click load more**

```
$apiur='https://mywebsiteapi.com';
  $user_data = "name=test";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiur);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array 
    ("User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-G973N Build/PPR1.190810.011)"));   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $user_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
 $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),TRUE);
    $dalil_so3de  = $result["t"];
curl_close($ch);

$lastid = array_slice(end($dalil_so3de), 0, 1)["ID"];

if (!empty($dalil_so3de[0]["ID"])) {

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($dalil_so3de); $i++)
    {
    $data[] = [
            'name' =>$dalil_so3de[$i]['Name'],
            'phone' => $dalil_so3de[$i]['Phone'] 
                ];
};
};
echo "<table>
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>phone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  "
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++)
    {
 
            echo" <td>".$data[$i]['Name']."</td>";
            echo" <td>". $data[$i]['Phone'] ."</td>";
            
};
echo "</tr>";
```

I want to **send another post requst with different data** and add new data in the same table by click **load more data button below the table**
I tried **using AJAX** but it didn't work because all the lessons talk about extracting data from MySQL

I also tried to put the code on another page and extract the data **via a form**, but it did not work

```
$data ='[{"name":"\u0639\u0645\u0631\u0648 \u0633\u0644\u064a\u0645","phone":"+201121712295"},{"name":"\u062f\/\u0639\u0645\u0631\u0648 \u0633\u0644\u064a\u0645","phone":"+201156996126"},{"name":"\u0639\u0645\u0631\u0648 \u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f \u0633\u0644\u064a\u0645","phone":"+201200211357"}]';
$user_data ='usuid=76593520&devuid=c3675a1c63b7970712345&nid=amr selim&fcntry=20&l_l_id=450511189';

echo '
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js"
  integrity="sha256-HwWONEZrpuoh951cQD1ov2HUK5zA5DwJ1DNUXaM6FsY="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div>
<form id="formupload" method="post" action="m.php>
<input type="hidden" id="data" name="data" value="'.$data.'">
<input type="hidden" id="user_data" name="user_data" value="'.$user_data.'">
 <input type="submit" value="Add" />

</form>
</div>

<script>
     $("#formupload").on("submit",function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
         var formData = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: $("#formupload").attr("action"),
                data:formData,
                cache:false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(result){
         if(condition){}
         else{}
    }
    })
   })

</script>


';
```

**m.php code**

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
$user_data = $_POST["user_data"];



  $apiur='https://mywebsiteapi.com';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiur);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array 
    ("User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-G973N Build/PPR1.190810.011)"));   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $user_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
 $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),TRUE);
    $dalil_so3de  = $result["t"];
curl_close($ch);

$dalil_so3de_lastid = array_slice(end($dalil_so3de), 0, 1)["ID"];

if (!empty($dalil_so3de[0]["ID"])) {

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($dalil_so3de); $i++)
    {
    $data[] = [
            'name' =>$dalil_so3de[$i]['Name'],
            'phone' => $dalil_so3de[$i]['Phone'] 
                ];
};
};

print_r ($data);
```

Comment: Include an empty table to the markup, and response with rows only from the API, then add the rows to the existing table.

Comment: how can i add append row in the html page

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/append/#append-content-content